# apache starts but stops right away

Tags: apache

For a while now I can't start apache.
(I don't have skype running)

I have tried googling it but no help.
I tried reinstaling, same thing. Tried easyphp, same thing happens to it too.
When I start it it says it started, but few seconds later it says it has stoped, and shows an error

> 20:39:59  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache service...
>   20:40:01  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
>   20:40:06  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Error log file:

```
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:01.984375 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3940:tid 248] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:02.703125 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3940:tid 248] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:02.921875 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3940:tid 248] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:02.921875 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3940:tid 248] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34  
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:02.921875 2013] [core:notice] [pid 3940:tid 248] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\program files\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files/xampp/apache'
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:02.921875 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3940:tid 248] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2176  
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:04.875000 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2176:tid 1876] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:05.734375 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2176:tid 1876] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:05.984375 2013] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 2176:tid 1876] (OS 10022)An invalid argument was supplied.  : AH00405: Child: WSASocket failed to open the inherited socket  
[Mon Nov 11 20:40:05.984375 2013] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 3940:tid 248] AH00427: Parent: child process 2176 exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

Hope someone knows what the problem is

Comment: Did you add virtual hosts on your httpd-vhosts.conf?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have ssl improperly configured for one of your domains (www.example.com). Try commenting out `Include (path)/(to)/httpd-ssl.conf` include line and `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` in your **httpd.conf** file.

If the commenting out of the ssl config works, it may be that the SSL port (443) is in use on your machine. Uncomment the above, then in **httpd-ssl.conf**, try changing line(s) `Listen 443` to an alternative (not-in-use) port number, i.e. `Listen 49199`.

At the command line, you can use `netstat -aon` to see what ports are currently in use on your machine.

Comment: Commented LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so and Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf but nothing changed

Comment: actually when I comment it is doesn't put the [ssl:warn] lines in the error.log (the ons that end with "...an ID which matches the server name"), the other lines are still putted in the error.log

Comment: It still looks like port overlap to me.  Are you using httpd-vhosts.conf? If so, look in there and confirm that your vhost entries are listening on port 80 (`Listen 80`).  Then, confirm that nothing is using port 80 locally by running netstat -aon.

Comment: httpd-vhosts.conf is empty (has only some comments), but when I put Listen 80 in there and start apachi nothing happensat all, it attempts to start it and that is that, noting is added to error.log

Comment: OK. Comment out the reference to httpd-vhosts.conf in the httpd.conf file.  Look for the `Listen` line in httpd.conf and confirm that it's set to 80.  What do you see when you run `netstat -aon`? And comment out the httpd-ssl.conf stuff again (as it seems you're not using it).

Comment: Yes it is 80. And there is nothing unusual in netstart, when I start apache it shows that it uses 80,443 for a second and that is all. By "httpd-ssl.conf stuff" did you mean the 2 things in httpd.conf ?